# Django filter only on aggregate/annotate

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to construct a fairly complicated Django query and I'm not making much progress. I was hoping some wizard here could help me out?

I have the following models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    MALE = "M"
    FEMALE = "F"
    OTHER = "O"
    UNKNOWN = "U"
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
            (MALE, "Male"),
            (FEMALE, "Female"),
            (UNKNOWN, "Other"),
    )


    firstName       = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, db_column="firstname")
    lastName        = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, db_column="lastname")

    gender          = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=UNKNOWN, null=True)
    dateOfBirth     = models.DateField(null=True, db_column="dateofbirth")
    dateInService   = models.DateField(null=True, db_column="dateinservice")
    photo           = models.ImageField(upload_to='person_photos', null=True) 

class SuccessionTerm(models.Model):
    originalName    = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, db_column="originalname")
    description     = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    score           = models.IntegerField()

class Succession(model.Model):
    position    = models.ForeignKey(Position, to_field='positionId', db_column="position_id")
    employee    = models.ForeignKey(Employee, to_field='employeeId', db_column="employee_id")
    term        = models.ForeignKey(SuccessionTerm)

class Position(models.Model):
    positionId      = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, db_column="positionid")
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    # There cannot be a DB constraint, as that would make it impossible to add the first position.
    dottedLine      = models.ForeignKey("Position", to_field='positionId', related_name="Dotted Line",
                                        null=True, db_constraint=False, db_column="dottedline_id")
    solidLine       = models.ForeignKey("Position", to_field='positionId', related_name="SolidLine", 
                                        null=True, db_constraint=False, db_column="solidline_id")
    grade           = models.ForeignKey(Grade)
    businessUnit    = models.ForeignKey(BusinessUnit, null=True, db_column="businessunit_id")
    functionalArea  = models.ForeignKey(FunctionalArea, db_column="functionalarea_id")
    location        = models.ForeignKey(Location, db_column="location_id")

class Employee(models.Model):
    person                = models.OneToOneField(Person, db_column="person_id")
    fte                   = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    dataSource            = models.ForeignKey(DataSource, db_column="datasource_id")
    talentStatus          = models.ForeignKey(TalentStatus, db_column="talentstatus_id")
    retentionRisk         = models.ForeignKey(RetentionRisk, db_column="retentionrisk_id")
    retentionRiskReason   = models.ForeignKey(RetentionRiskReason, db_column="retentionriskreason_id")
    performanceStatus     = models.ForeignKey(PerformanceStatus, db_column="performancestatus_id")
    potential             = models.ForeignKey(Potential, db_column="potential_id")
    mobility              = models.ForeignKey(Mobility, db_column="mobility_id")
    currency              = models.ForeignKey(Currency, null=True, db_column="currency_id")
    grade                 = models.ForeignKey(Grade, db_column="grade_id")
    position              = models.OneToOneField(Position, to_field='positionId', null=True, 
                                                 blank=True, db_column="position_id")
    employeeId            = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, db_column="employeeid")
    dateInPosition        = models.DateField(null=True, db_column="dateinposition")
```

Now, what I want is for each employee to get the position title, the person's name, and for each succession term (of which there are three) how many times the position of that employee is in the succession table, and the number of times each of these employees occurs in the successors table. Above all, I want to do all of this in a singe query (or more specifically, a single Django ORM statement), as I'm doing this in a paginated way, but I want to be able to order the result on any of these columns!

So far, I have this:

```
emps = Employee.objects.all()
       .annotate(ls_st=Count('succession__term'))
       .filter(succession__term__description="ShortTerm")
       .order_by(ls_st)
       .prefetch_related('person', 'position')[lower_limit:upper_limit]
```

This is only one of the succession terms, and I would like to extend it to all terms by adding more annotate calls. 
My problem is that the filter call works on the entire query. I would like to only filter on the Count call.

I've tried doing something like `Count(succession__term__description'="ShortTerm")` but that doesn't work. Is there any other way to do this?

Thank you very much in advance,
Regards,

Linus

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is a count of each different type of succession__term? That is pretty complex, and I don't think you can do this with the built in django orm right now. (unless you did a `.extra()` query)

In django 1.8, I believe you will be able to do it with the new Query Expressions (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/#query-expressions). But of course 1.8 isn't released yet, so that doesn't help you.

In the meantime, you can use the very handy django-aggregate-if package. (https://github.com/henriquebastos/django-aggregate-if/, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-aggregate-if)

With django-aggregate-if, your query might look like this:

```
emps = Employee.objects.annotate(
        ls_st=Count('succession__term', only=Q(succession__term__description="ShortTerm")),
        ls_lt=Count('succession__term', only=Q(succession__term__description="LongTerm")), # whatever your other term descriptions are.
        ls_ot=Count('succession__term', only=Q(succession__term__description="OtherTerm"))
    )
    .order_by('ls_st')
    .prefetch_related('person', 'position')[lower_limit:upper_limit]
```

Disclaimer: I have never used django-aggregate-if, so I'm not entirely sure if this will work, but according the the README, it seems like it should.